# JSON.net Deserialization failing with doublequotes in json

Tags: javascript, ajax, serialization, json.net

I have an object that is being serialized by JSON.net, sent to a javascript client which converts it into a javascript object.  The object may be edited by the user, and then javascript converts it back to json using `JSON.stringify(myObject)` and passes it back via ajax to a method that uses JSON.net to deserialize the json back into the original object.

All of this works fine-and-dandy until I have a value on the object that contains a double quote, at which point, the JSON.net deserialization fails.

Here is an example of the JSON that is being sent up to JSON.net for deserialization:

```
"{
   \"$id\":\"1\",
   \"Treatment_ID\":36050,
   \"Project_Classification\":\"MCPM\",
   \"Improvement_Type\":\"Cape Seal\",
   \"Jurisdiction\":\"24120\",
   \"Description\":\"\",
   \"Planned\":true,
   \"Comment\":\"test22 2\"\"
}"
```

All the double-quotes are being escaped automatically.  If they weren't being escaped, the json would look more like this:

```
"{
   "$id":"1",
   "Treatment_ID":36050,
   "Project_Classification":"MCPM",
   "Improvement_Type":"Cape Seal",
   "Jurisdiction":"24120",
   "Description":"",
   "Planned":true,
   "Comment":"test22 2\""
}"
```

How do I overcome this behavior?

Comment: Are you relying on a browser's implementation of JSON.stringify or a library's? JSON.stringify should only be escaping the double quote within the value of "Comment".

Comment: I believe it is the browser implementation.  I don't have any references in my javascript where I am defining JSON as something else.  The example above is in FireFox 9.

Comment: @AmandaMyer - if you think the problem is browser-specific, try [Douglas Crockord's stringifier](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Answer (score 0):

The undesired form of your JSON has only one backslash in front of the offending quote, just as many as the quotes used for the JSON structure itself. My guess is it should have three: two to make a 'real' backslash character in the resulting string, one more to make the quote not end the string. (Note that the thing you currently have does not make sense as either a string or an object, a fact brought out by SO's code highlighting)

From your question, I can't quite tell where the "All the double-quotes are being escaped automatically" happens. No browser does this in `JSON.stringify`. I would expect JSON.net not to mess with things, either. So, either the client-side that does the ajax request, or the intermediary stuff on the server which passes it to JSON.net is breaking. You'd need to post more details about what is there in order to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Well, according to firebug, FireFox is doing this.  I looked at the result for JSON.stringify(myObject) in FireBug and it shows the result exactly like the first example I posted.  When I examine the object prior to the stringify action, the "Comment" field is set to "test 2\"".

Comment: Don't trust Firebug. It does funny things to string quoting to make variables 'more readable'. Instead, in the console, run: `alert(JSON.stringify(myObject).toSource())` which will produce valid JS which you can use to check the data in the string.

Comment: Better yet, look at the data that is actually being sent to your server with something like Live HTTP Headers.